# Android Auto Message Sending

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps

i want to develop an android application to locate a mobile no.Obviously it cannot be done without user approval.
Basically i need the GPS coordinates of the other user.So my idea is to, after selecting a contact from the list,when i click on locate Button a automatic message/notifaction is sent to the other user asking for his/her permission to Allow/Deny.Once the user clicks on the allow button an automatic msg will be sent to the locator giving the longitudes,latitudes of the mobile which i can locate using GPS

Comment: This question is really vague, what kind of message do you want to send? IM, Email, or SMS?

Comment: Are you having trouble with a specific part of the idea? Please be more specific about what part of the application you are having trouble with.

Comment: your question is not clear pls clarify it and give more detail.

Comment: This isn't even really a questions. At least show some effort

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, on the receiving end, a `Service` will be monitoring for Events (on Bluetooth or Wifi) and should popup a dialog requiring user to accept or deny a transaction.

You can quite easily make an `Activity` that polls for Event (or better, make a `bounded` background `Service` `Message` your `Activity` when a new Event has been detected) and display a popup `AlertDialog`. If you design it this way you will need your Activity to be active and running (i.e. displayed).

If you need your application to get user attention even when your application is not displayed, you will not be able to do so: you can *not* (nor should) directly start an `Activity` from within a `Service`. You will have to use `Notification`s and/or a `Toast` message to unintrusively notify your user that something requires his/her attention. `Notification`s appear in the status bar and can be used to launch your Accept/Deny `Activity`.

Comment: yes,you got me right.It is all about notifiaction.But iam unable to find any tutorial or sample code to do this work...

Comment: I highlighted the keywords in my answer, they will help you find those tutorials. I recommend android developers website.

Comment: Thank u sir,I refered to these tutorials and learnt much but reading this i can send send notification on the same emulator(but not to other system/emulator).Is it possible to send notification from one system to another system(one emulator to another emulator)???

Comment: I suggest that you add a debug mode where you send your notification from the same device as the receiving part. I'm not familiar with BT/Wifi debugging on the emulator.

Comment: sir I am sorry but i am not getting you there exactly. What exactly my problem is even though i am able to locate the emulator on which the application is running i still got no clue to how to locate another emluator..Right now my idea is to send a notification to the other device/emulator and as the person on the other end allow me to locate him/her then my application will locate that device/emulator..

Comment: Sorry, it seems that bluetooth debugging is really limited on the emulator. My advice is that you separately test your service/notification using a BroadcastReceiver for example, then test Bluetooth connectivity using two physical devices.